# Scripting Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I have a test AppleScript dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">

<dictionary title="ScriptTest Terminology">

    <suite name="Standard Suite" code="????" description="Common classes and commands for all applications.">
        <class name="application" code="capp" description="The application's top-level scripting object.">
            <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>
        </class>
    </suite>


    <suite name="MyApplication Suite" code="scts" description="MyApplication information.">
        <class name="application" code="capp" description="The application's top-level scripting object." inherits="application">
            <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>

            <responds-to command="sayhello">
                <cocoa method="sayHello:"/>
            </responds-to>

        </class>

        <command name="sayhello" code="sctshell" description="Says hello.">
        </command>
    </suite>

</dictionary>
```

My AppDelegate has method:

```
- (void)sayHello:(NSScriptCommand*)scriptCommand;
```

But it's never called.. Why?

How can I add commands to my application class in appleScript? (e.g. `tell application
 "Test" to sayhello`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's [SimpleScriptingVerbs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/samplecode/SimpleScriptingVerbs/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. Your sdef definition of the sayhello command should name the subclass of `NSScriptCommand` that implements the command:

```
<command name="sayhello" code="sctshell" description="Says hello.">
    <cocoa class="SayHelloCommand"/>
</command>
```

Then implement `SayHelloCommand` as a subclass of `NSScriptCommand` and override its `performDefaultImplementation` method.